# Como saber se um determinado Actor não existe

Tags: java, modelo-de-atores, akka

Estou trabalhando com a Akka/Java

Uma referencia à um ator que não existe, simplesmente *não* retorna exceção e/ou não sei como capturar informações que o ator não existe no sistema de atores.

```
ActorSelection register = null;
register = actorSystem.actorSelection("akka://default/user/ATOR-NAO-EXISTE");
```

Percebí também que o path de register é `akka://default/` não está completo.

Esse ator não existe, mas também não gera erros.

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a funcção resolveOne do [ActorSelection](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSelection)

java:

```
final ExecutionContext ec = system.dispatcher();

ActorSelection register = system.actorSelection("akka://default/user/ATOR-NAO-EXISTE");
Future future = register.resolveOne()
future.onSuccess(new OnSuccess() {
  public void onSuccess(ActorRef actor) {
    // the actor reference
  }
}, ec);

future.onFailure(new OnFailure() {
  public void onFailure(Throwable failure) {
    if (failure instanceof ActorNotFound) {
      // actor not found
    }
  }
}, ec);
```

scala:

```
val register = system.actorSelection("akka://default/user/ATOR-NAO-EXISTE");
val future  = register.resolveOne()
future.onSuccess({
    case actor: ActorRef => // the actor reference
  })

future.onFailure({
    case e: ActorNotFound => // actor not found
    case _ => // anything else
  })
```

Comment: Perfeita sua resposta!